# Xcode - Using TCP sockets with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sockets

I am trying to achieve a tcp connection between my Java application using Java sockets and my iOS App. I am coming from Android development and I am very new to Swift programming.

As far as I found, the [SwiftSocket API](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) is the most often used to write a client tcp connection.

I downloaded the project and added this files to my project:
[image: project setup]

Unfortunately i get this errors:
[image: errors]

I have not found any solution for this problem yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest an alternative TCPSocket library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using the latest version of xCode!

Comment: it's work but latest version of xcode don't have new SDK ios What will i do it ؟ @zFr3eak